# How to perform pthread_join operation on a thread whose handle has been created dynamically

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix

Need some help as I unable to perform pthread_join operation.
I have a thread handle which has been created dynamically

```
void *threadHandle;
threadHandle = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
```

I cannot create handle by value.
The thread is getting created successfully.
However, when I am trying to do pthread_join, I am getting segmentation fault.
pthread_join takes handle which has been created by value.
Is there any way I could do this operation ?

Edit:
Adding both the functions which are responsible for creating and joining the thread:

```
int care_thread_create(void *threadHandle, void *attr, void *(*start_routine)(void *), void *args)
{
    printf("Thread Creation Started \n");
    threadHandle = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
    int returnValue = pthread_create(threadHandle, (pthread_attr_t *)attr, start_routine, args);
    printf("Thread Creation Completed \n");
    return returnValue;
}

int care_thread_join(void *threadHandle)
{
    int returnValue = pthread_join(*(pthread_t*)threadHandle, NULL);
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Why do you create such a mess with types? Casting result of `malloc` is generally not needed and not adviced. Casting to a type that is not the type of the variable you assign it to is completely useless. If you want to have a pointer to `pthread_t` use a pointer to `pthread_t`, not `void*`.

Comment: Without seeing what you are doing we cannot tell anything. Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ashutosh I see that you edited your question long after I answered it. I've now updated the answer. If there's anything in my answer that you want me to clarify, please just ask.

Answer (score 1):

You join it just like you would with a handle allocated automatically.

The signature of `pthread_join` is

```c
int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);
```

This means that if you have a `pthread_t*` you need to dereference that pointer to supply a `pthread_t` argument to `pthread_join()`.

Example:

```c
#include <pthread.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* threadfunc(void* vptr) {
    puts("in thread");
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t *threadHandle; // Note: Use the proper type

    threadHandle = malloc(sizeof *threadHandle);
    if(threadHandle == NULL) return 1;

    if(pthread_create(threadHandle, NULL, threadfunc, NULL) == 0) {
        // ...
        pthread_join(*threadHandle, NULL); // join by dereferencing threadHandle
    }

    free(threadHandle);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6do7nKjan)

---

I'll extend this to address the issues I see with the functions you've added to the question.

**You are using the wrong types! Don't use `void*`, use `pthread_t*` and `pthread_attr_t*`**

Not only is it correct - it actually helps you to create the program since the compiler will complain if you use the wrong type. You actually do not need ***any*** casts for this.

A naive fix to that problem  (warning - don't use this version):

```c
#include <pthread.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* threadfunc(void* vptr) {
    (void)vptr; // discard warnings about the unused variable

    puts("in thread");
    return NULL;
}

// note: you need a `pthread_t**` here:
int care_thread_create(pthread_t **threadHandle, pthread_attr_t *attr,
                       void *(*start_routine)(void *), void *args)
{
    *threadHandle = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
    int returnValue = pthread_create(*threadHandle, attr, start_routine, args);
    return returnValue;
}

int care_thread_join(pthread_t *threadHandle)
{
    int returnValue = pthread_join(*threadHandle, NULL);
    free(threadHandle);
    return returnValue;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t *threadHandle; // Note: Use the proper type
    if(care_thread_create(&threadHandle, NULL, threadfunc, NULL) == 0) {
        // ...
        care_thread_join(threadHandle);
    }
}
```

The keen eye may see a problem here. What if starting the thread fails?  Yes, the program will then leak the memory allocated in `care_thread_create`. Also, if memory allocation failed in `care_thread_create`, then you'd call `pthread_create` with a `NULL` pointer and get *undefined behavior*.

Here are possible fixes for that:

```c
#include <pthread.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* threadfunc(void* vptr) {
    (void)vptr; // discard warnings about the unused variable

    puts("in thread");
    return NULL;
}

// don't pass in a pointer, just let the function allocate and return it to you
pthread_t *care_thread_create(pthread_attr_t *attr,
                              void *(*start_routine)(void *), void *args)
{
    pthread_t *threadHandle = malloc(sizeof *threadHandle);
    if(threadHandle == NULL) return NULL; // if allocation failed
    
    if(pthread_create(threadHandle, attr, start_routine, args)) {
        // if creating the thread failed, free the allocated memory
        free(threadHandle);
        return NULL; // and return NULL
    }

    return threadHandle; // success
}

int care_thread_join(pthread_t *threadHandle)
{
    int returnValue = pthread_join(*threadHandle, NULL);
    if(returnValue == 0) free(threadHandle);
    return returnValue;
}

int main() {
    // simpler interface for the user:
    pthread_t *threadHandle = care_thread_create(NULL, threadfunc, NULL);

    if(threadHandle) {
        // memory allocated and thread successfully started
        // ...
        care_thread_join(threadHandle); // joins and free's
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6W64zvPjz)

---

If you need to handle both Windows and Posix, you can hide the `pthread_t*` or `HANDLE*` in a `struct` to provide the user of the library type checking when developing.

`mythread.h`:

```c
#pragma once
// this is defined in the common header for Windows and Posix:
typedef struct { void *thread; } mythread_t;
#define MYTHREAD_STARTED(x) ((x).thread != NULL)
```

And this would be the posix implementation part:

```c
#include "mythread.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

mythread_t care_thread_create(void *attr,
                              void *(*start_routine)(void *), void *args)
{
    mythread_t retval = {.thread = NULL};
    pthread_t *pt = malloc(sizeof *pt);
    if(pt == NULL) return retval; // if allocation failed

    if(pthread_create(pt, attr, start_routine, args)) {
        free(pt);
        return retval;
    }

    // success, put the `pthread_t*` in the return value:
    retval.thread = pt;

    return retval;
}

int care_thread_join(mythread_t *threadHandle)
{
    pthread_t *pt = threadHandle->thread;
    int returnValue = pthread_join(*pt, NULL);
    if(returnValue == 0) {
        threadHandle->thread = NULL;
        free(pt);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Example usage:

```
int main() {
    mythread_t threadHandle = care_thread_create(NULL, threadfunc, NULL);

    if(MYTHREAD_STARTED(threadHandle)) {
        // memory allocated and thread successfully started
        // ...
        care_thread_join(&threadHandle); // joins and free's
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zoPEac3Ex)

Comment: Thank you Ted for taking out time in solving my problem.
The reason, why I cannot use pthread_t* is because this code is part of platform dependent library, and the call is coming from a file which is platform independent. Similar function will be present in windows specific library as well. 
So I cannot accept pthread_t as function argument,  or provide pthread_t variable as return type, as it will cause a compilation error on windows platform

Comment: Ok, then `#ifdef _WIN32` `typedef MYTHREAD HANDLE*;` `#else` `typedef MYTHREAD pthread_t*` `#endif` or similar, then use `MYTHREAD` everywhere. Should the `care_thread_create` functions be able to create threads in both Windows and Posix? If so, can't you use [standard C threads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) instead? That would certainly simplify things since you wouldn't need to implement two different solutions.

Comment: I don't think the architects would approve the usage of #ifdefs, however I will explore the standard C Threads. Thank you once again for answering my query

Comment: @ashutosh I checked it out and it doesn't seem like the Visual Studio compiler supports standard threads. :-( Otherwise, the program would look [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/h8zGxaPEG). If the architects don't allow `#ifdef`s, how are you going to implement `care_thread_create` (if it's supposed to support both Windows and Posix)?

Comment: so care_thread_func and others will be part of a library which will have all the platform dependent code. at the time of compilation we will choose whether we have to generate a DLL of files present in windows_platform/care_thread_func or a *.so of files present in linux_platform/care_thread_func.
accordingly the library will be linked to the code which is platform independent.

Comment: @ashutosh Ok, good. Then your posix-only version of `care_thread_create` must have exactly the same interface as the windows version of `care_thread_create`, right? To do this properly, don't pass `void*` around. Make a proper, but opaque, type: `typedef struct {void *thread; } mythread_t;` and inside all the functions in the Posix version, you cast to `(pthread_t*)thread;` before doing anything else. In the Windows part, you cast to `(HANDLE*)thread;` before doing anything else.

Comment: @ashutosh Another thing. Windows thread functions do not return a `void*` so the interface for `care_thread_create` can't include `void *(*start_routine)(void *)`, right? Anyway, to show what I meant about making a proper type, I updated the answer with that. You hide the pointer. With this interface, you'd store `mythread_t` objects everywhere. Not `void*`. Your compiler will then tell you, or the user of the interface, if the wrong type is used. No casts needed on the user side.